Writing AST Matchers for a libTooling code transformer tool
I am writing a stand alone C++ tool to instrument 'C' code using clang libTooling ASTMatcher/Rewriter APIs.
I wrote some simple AST matchers to rewrite the source.  These matchers are used to find 'functionDecls', 'switch', 'if', 'else if' and some 'case' statements.  This works well for very simple examples, however some difficult cases are beyond my ability and I need help with these. For example:
How can I develop a matcher to locate the position following the last uninitialized local variable? i.e. line 23 below. I need to insert code after this line - my sample code below inserts the code following the opening brace of the function which is not quite right (i.e. inserts new code between lines 20 & 21).

Also, how can I find the location of 'expr' in a the simple switch (expr) ...

I dumped the AST for this expression below.  I also need to take this expr string (whatever it was in the code before) and replace it with something like 'foo(expr)' just as an example.  Clang's rewriter API has a function to replace the text - but this does not preserve the existing text - I would apply similar logic to the if statement handlers if I can solve this problem:
    //! This is where the magic happens.
    void run(const MatchFinder::MatchResult& result) override {
        const auto ifStmt = result.Nodes.getNodeAs<IfStmt>("ifStmt");
        if (ifStmt->getCond()) {
            // replace the condition within the 'if (...) {}' statement parenthesis.
            mRewriter.ReplaceText(ifStmt->getCond()->getSourceRange(),
                "_sp(_co(expr, 0, probeNum), probeNum)");
        }
    }


Here the tooling C++ code that I use to match and rewrite some simple cases:
// SYSTEM INCLUDES
#include <string>
#pragma warning(push)
#pragma warning(disable : 4146 4267 4291 4100 4244 4624)
#include <clang/Tooling/Tooling.h>
#include <clang/Tooling/CommonOptionsParser.h>
#include <clang/AST/ASTConsumer.h>
#include <clang/ASTMatchers/ASTMatchers.h>
#include <clang/ASTMatchers/ASTMatchFinder.h>
#include <clang/Frontend/CompilerInstance.h>
#include <clang/Rewrite/Core/Rewriter.h>
#include <llvm/Support/raw_ostream.h>
#pragma warning(pop)

// APPLICATION INCLUDES
#include "ProbeUtils.h"

// EXTERNAL FUNCTIONS
// EXTERNAL VARIABLES
// CONSTANTS
// DEFINES
// NAMESPACE USAGE
using namespace llvm;
using namespace clang;
using namespace clang::driver;
using namespace clang::tooling;
using namespace clang::ast_matchers;
namespace fs = std::filesystem;

// STATIC VARIABLE INITIALIZATIONS
namespace {
    static llvm::cl::OptionCategory gToolCategory("CProbe Tool Category");
}

namespace tooling {
    class EntryHandler : public MatchFinder::MatchCallback {
    public:
        explicit EntryHandler(Rewriter& rewriter)
            : mRewriter(rewriter)
        {}

        //! This is where the magic happens.
        void run(const MatchFinder::MatchResult &result) override {
            const auto fd = result.Nodes.getNodeAs<FunctionDecl>("functionDecl");
            if (fd->doesThisDeclarationHaveABody()) {
                SourceLocation sl = fd->getBody()->getBeginLoc();
                // insert the probe at the beginning of the function body.
                mRewriter.InsertText(sl.getLocWithOffset(1),
                    "\n\t_sp(_co(0, 0, 0), 0);\n", true, true);
            }
        }
    private:
        Rewriter& mRewriter;
    };

    // 'if' & 'else_if' Handler.
    class IfStmtHandler : public MatchFinder::MatchCallback {
    public:
        //! Constructor.
        explicit IfStmtHandler(Rewriter& rewriter)
        : mRewriter(rewriter)
        {}

        //! This is where the magic happens.
        void run(const MatchFinder::MatchResult& result) override {
            const auto ifStmt = result.Nodes.getNodeAs<IfStmt>("ifStmt");
            if (ifStmt->getCond()) {
                // replace the condition within the 'if (...) {}' statement parenthesis.
                mRewriter.ReplaceText(ifStmt->getCond()->getSourceRange(),
                    "_sp(_co(expr, 0, probeNum), probeNum)");
            }
        }
    private:
        Rewriter& mRewriter;
    };

    class ElseIfHandler : public MatchFinder::MatchCallback {
    public:
        explicit ElseIfHandler(Rewriter&rewriter)
            : mRewriter(rewriter)
        {}

        virtual void run(const MatchFinder::MatchResult &Result) {
            const auto ifStmt = Result.Nodes.getNodeAs<IfStmt>("elseIf");
            if (ifStmt->getThen()) {
                SourceLocation sl = ifStmt->getThen()->getBeginLoc();
                mRewriter.InsertText(sl.getLocWithOffset(1),
                    "_sp(_co(expr, 0, probeNum), probeNum)", true, false);
            }
        }
    private:
        Rewriter& mRewriter;
    };

    // Switch statement handler.
    class SwitchStmtHandler : public MatchFinder::MatchCallback {
    public:
        //! Constructor.
        explicit SwitchStmtHandler(Rewriter& rewriter)
            : mRewriter(rewriter)
        {}

        //! This is where the magic happens.
        void run(const MatchFinder::MatchResult& result) override {
            // The matched 'if' statement was bound to 'ifElseIf'.
            if (const auto switchStmt = result.Nodes.getNodeAs<clang::SwitchStmt>("switchStmt")) {
                const auto switchBody = switchStmt->getBody();
                auto foo = mRewriter.InsertText(switchBody->getBeginLoc(),
                    "/* 'switch' */", true, true);
            }
        }
    private:
        Rewriter& mRewriter;
    };

    // Not used yet, we might use this for additional coverage later
    // as the other half of the 'entry' aka functionDecl handler.
    class ReturnStmtHandler : public MatchFinder::MatchCallback {
    public:
        explicit ReturnStmtHandler(Rewriter &rewriter)
            : mRewriter(rewriter)
        {}

        void run(const MatchFinder::MatchResult &Result) override {
            const auto returnStmt = Result.Nodes.getNodeAs<ReturnStmt>("returnStmt");
            mRewriter.InsertText(returnStmt->getBeginLoc(),
                "// Inserted comment\n", true, false);
        }
    private:
        Rewriter &mRewriter;
    };

    // ASTConsumer implementation reads AST produced by the Clang parser.
    // Here we register our instrumentation matchers and run them against the AST.
    class MyASTConsumer : public ASTConsumer {
    public:
        MyASTConsumer(Rewriter& r)
        : mEntryHandler(r)
        , mIfHandler(r)
        , mElseIfHandler(r)
        , mSwitchHandler(r)
        , mReturnHandler(r) {
            // Add for finding function entry declarations.
            mMatcher.addMatcher(functionDecl().bind("functionDecl"), &mEntryHandler);
            // Add matcher for finding 'if', 'else_if' & 'else' statements.
            mMatcher.addMatcher(ifStmt().bind("ifStmt"), &mIfHandler);
            // Add matcher for finding 'if', 'else_if' & 'else' statements.
            mMatcher.addMatcher(ifStmt(hasElse(ifStmt())).bind("elseIf"), &mElseIfHandler);
            // Add matcher for switch(...) statements.
            mMatcher.addMatcher(switchStmt().bind("switchStmt"), &mSwitchHandler);
            // Add matcher for finding 'if', 'else_if' & 'else' statements.
            mMatcher.addMatcher(returnStmt().bind("returnStmt"), &mReturnHandler);
        }

        void HandleTranslationUnit(ASTContext& context) override {
            // Run the matchers when we have the whole TU parsed.
            mMatcher.matchAST(context);
        }

    private:
        EntryHandler mEntryHandler;
        IfStmtHandler mIfHandler;
        ElseIfHandler mElseIfHandler;
        SwitchStmtHandler mSwitchHandler;
        ReturnStmtHandler mReturnHandler;
        MatchFinder mMatcher;
    };

    // For each source file provided to the tool, a new FrontendAction is created.
    class CProbeFrontEndAction : public ASTFrontendAction {
    public:
        //! explicit Constructor - pass the output path to write the instrumented source.
        explicit CProbeFrontEndAction(fs::path rOutputPath)
        : mOutputPath(std::move(rOutputPath))
        {}

        //! This function is called after parsing the source file.
        void EndSourceFileAction() override {
            const auto& sm = mRewriter.getSourceMgr();
            std::error_code error_code;
            raw_fd_ostream outFile(
                mOutputPath.generic_string(),
                error_code, sys::fs::OF_None);
            // write the result to outFile
            mRewriter.getEditBuffer(sm.getMainFileID()).write(outFile);
            outFile.close();
        }

        std::unique_ptr<ASTConsumer> CreateASTConsumer(CompilerInstance& CI, StringRef file) override {
            mRewriter.setSourceMgr(CI.getSourceManager(), CI.getLangOpts());
            return std::make_unique<MyASTConsumer>(mRewriter);
        }
    private:
        fs::path mOutputPath;
        Rewriter mRewriter;
    };

    //! Factory function for creating a new FrontendAction that takes a user parameter.
    std::unique_ptr<FrontendActionFactory> myNewFrontendActionFactory(const fs::path& rOutputPath) {
        class SimpleFrontendActionFactory : public FrontendActionFactory {
        public:
            explicit SimpleFrontendActionFactory(fs::path aOutputPath)
                : mOutputPath(std::move(aOutputPath))
            {}

            std::unique_ptr<FrontendAction> create() override {
                return std::make_unique<CProbeFrontEndAction>(mOutputPath);
            }
        private:
            fs::path mOutputPath;
        };
        return std::make_unique<SimpleFrontendActionFactory>(rOutputPath);
    }

    // Instrument the source code - rewriting it to rOutputPath.
    void instrumentSource(const fs::path& rInputPath, const fs::path& rOutputPath) {
        std::string program = "foo.exe";
        std::string inputPath = rInputPath.generic_string();
        std::string outputPath = rOutputPath.generic_string();
        const char* argv[] = { program.data(), inputPath.data(), "--", nullptr };
        int argc = 3;
        auto expectedParser = CommonOptionsParser::create(
            argc, argv, gToolCategory);
        if (expectedParser) {
            CommonOptionsParser& optionsParser = expectedParser.get();
            ClangTool tool(optionsParser.getCompilations(), optionsParser.getSourcePathList());
            tool.run(myNewFrontendActionFactory(rOutputPath.generic_string()).get());
        }
    }
}


For greater accessibility, it would be good to replace the screenshots of text and code with fenced code blocks.  The loss of color highlighting isn't important, and the annotations can be done using comments.  See: Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.

Thank you Scott, I will try to make the adjustments (I did so for the colorization & line numbers).

If I understand correctly, there are two questions here: 1. How do I find the location after the last uninitialized local variable declaration in a function definition?  2. How do I find and instrument the condition expression of a switch statement?  If this is right, I think this question should be split in two since these questions aren't closely related.
